# What would you call it when we generate data from a model and use that same data to estimate the model parameters?

Tags: regression, modeling

As per the title: what would you call it when we generate data from a model and use that same data to estimate the model parameters?

Suppose I have an ODE model of a process and I solve the IVP for this model, thus generating a series of datapoints.
I then use some of these datapoints to estimate the parameters of the original model, for example by lstq regression.

I'm trying to find some literature but I'm not sure what you'd call this pipeline.
Would it be a so-called autoregressive model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely not an "autoregressive" model, which is a [time series process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) where today's realizations depend on last week's realizations, and the ones from the week(s) before that. So: something completely different.

I do not think there is a specific name for this process, beyond "simulation". A procedure like this can be useful when we are interested in finding out how well a model building algorithm performs in recovering a *known* underlying data generating process.

For instance, we might *simulate* an autoregressive time series of order $p$, run the simulated data through an AR fitting algorithm and check whether it will recover the original order $p$, and how closely the fitted parameters match the ones used in the original simulation. (The answer is usually surprisingly disappointing.)

I have done similar things and never called them any different than a "simulation", with some words of explanation as to what precisely I was simulating.

Comment: I would call it simulation or bootstrapping in some cases, depending on how you simulated the data. Although with simulation you commonly create the data yourself, you make up the variable(s) from assumed distributions rather than use real data.

Comment: @user54285: [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) is something quite different.

Comment: Well you take real data and simulate another set of data from it. One with a very different distribution. But isn't bootstrapping a form of simulating data from known data?

Comment: @user54285: actually, you are right. It's a kind of parametric bootstrap, where you *simulate* from a known *distribution*. I was thinking of the "standard" bootstrap, where you *resample* from *observations*. Sorry, my bad for shooting too fast!

Comment: LOL I did not even make the distinction between simulating and resampling. I was actually thinking about a standard bootstrap. I thought the resampling, creating one distribution from another was simulation.